Help page still in need of update? (create chat rooms)
The privileges help page regarding chat, create chat rooms [sic], includes the text

How do I create a new chat room?
There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also
appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper right corner
of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a
new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.

I cannot see a link to chat in the footer of any page on Stack Overflow, but other SE sites have it. Should that text be removed, or should the link be added back?
It might be clearer if "the Stack Exchange site switcher" was referred to as "the Stack Exchange site switcher burger menu".
This has been a problem since the year 2017: Misleading directions in "participate in meta" and "talk in chat" help pages; SO Chat help pages - outdated access information.

I definitely vote for adding the link back. Along with the others that are missing on Stack Overflow but seen on other Stack Exchange sites. As for "[ham]burger menu", I suspect that this term still doesn't have universal enough recognition to be all that useful. To make it clearer, an guide with images is necessary. (One gets the impression that the company doesn't want you to create chat rooms. Or log out, for that matter.)

@KarlKnechtel You have a good point about the burger menu, and I should have remembered that I already remarked on there being too many of them: McStackIconOverflow.

Chat rooms seem to have multiple issues needing addressed.  Look at this post's comments.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/775423/254567

Tagged so CMs can see and review it. That page does need some updating.

I went ahead and added the link back to the footer.
Thanks for reminding us of that folks, we believe that the reasons for that not being there are no longer valid.
